# Question on strongly monotone, continuous and Lipschitzian function

Tags: continuity, lipschitz-functions, monotone-functions

Let $K\subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a closed, convex and non-empty set, $F\colon K\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be $\gamma$-strongly monotone and continuous on $K$.

Remind that a function $F$ is $\gamma$-strongly monotone on $K$ iff $$\langle F(x) - F(y), x - y \rangle \ge \gamma \|x-y\|^2, \quad \forall x, y\in K.$$

We can find a function satisfying the above conditions but not Lipschitzian on $K$, for example, $F_0(x, y) = (x - y^2, y+y^3)$.

However, $F_0$ is Lipschitzian on every bounded subset of $K$.

This arises a question:

> Is it true that strongly monotone and continuous function on $K$ also Lipschitzian on every bounded subset of $K$?

It seems impossible to prove the property, but finding a counter-example is pretty hard too.

Comment: I am not sure why you need it to be $\gamma$-strongly monotone. Every continuous function on a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^N$ is Lipshitz. $K$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and so it may not be closed, however, $F$ would be Lipshitz on the closure of $K$, which is compact.

Comment: @DanielBeale If $F:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ is monotone, then $F$ is differentiable a.e which implies $F$ is locally Lipschitz a.e. I want to ask for a similar property in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with stronger hypotheses. Anyway, I don't think every continuous function on a compact set is Lipschitz. Take $F(x) = \sqrt{x}$ if $0\le x\le 1$ and $F(x) = -\sqrt{-x}$ if $-1\le x\le 0$, then $F$ is continuous on $[-1, 1]$ but not Lipschitz.

Comment: Could you not use a similar counter example for your hypothesis? i.e. take $K=[0,1]$ and $F(x) = \sqrt{x}$. Then $F$ is continuous and monotone, but not Lipshitz on any set containing $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function defined by $F(x,y)=(2\sqrt{x},y)$ is $1$-strongly monotone on $[0,1]\times[0,1],$ because $2(\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{x'})(x-x')+(y-y')^2=2(x-x')^2/(\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{x'})+(y-y')^2.$ But it's not locally Lipschitz near $0:$ $F(x,0)/x=x^{-1/2}\to\infty$ as $x\to 0^+.$